# Unable to parse JSON string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, django

I'm sending JSON string from Django view to javascript file named `idbop.js` at the client side. I'm using the serializer in Django to convert query result in Django to JSON. Here is my code in views.py of Django

```
def index(request):
template='posts/index.html'
results=feed.objects.all()
jsondata = serializers.serialize('json',results)
context={
    'results':results,
    'jsondata':jsondata,
}
return render(request,template,context)
```

At client side, I'm accessing `jsondata` in javascript as follows:

```
var jsondata="{{jsondata}}".replace(/&quot;/g,"\"");
```

Here jsondata is in string format. If I try to parse it using, `var data = JSON.parse(jsondata);` It is throwing an error:`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line 1 column 344 of the JSON data` 
I'm having whitespace at 344 in `jsondata` but that whitespace is inside the string of value.
Here is my JSON string:

```
[
    {
        "model": "posts.feed",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {
            "author": "J Watson",
            "title": "Service Worker",
            "body": "A service worker is a type of web worker. It&#39;s essentially a JavaScript file that runs separately from the main browser thread, intercepting network requests, caching or retrieving resources from the cache, and delivering push messages.

Because workers run separately from the main thread, service workers are independent of the application they are associated with. This has several consequences:"
        }
    }]
```

Comment: Your JSON isn't using `&quot;`, but `&#39;`

Comment: Have you tried replacing the newlines of the `body` member?

Comment: You're better off using a real JSON serializer. `import json` and `json.dumps(results)`

Comment: Should I remove `&#39` ? And the original string is using `&quot` I printed `jsondata` in javascript after the statement   `var jsondata="{{jsondata}}".replace(/&quot;/g,"\"");`

Comment: @helb I think you are right. It is because of newline. Let me try escaping that newline

Comment: @JJJ What is the difference between this two approaches? I thought both will convert queryset result to json string.

Comment: @helb and TheIncorrigible1 you guys were right. It was because of the new line. Can you post it as an answer? So I can mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can **safely** insert your javascript content into your template with either [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) or [escapejs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs) builtins. With using safe:

```
var jsondata = {{ jsondata|safe }}
```

Or with using escapejs:

```
var jsondata = JSON.parse({{ jsondata|escapejs }})
```

Comment: I found out the root cause of the problem. Thanks for answering though. I'll definitely look into escapejs. I'm still new to web development. :)

Comment: Glad if you made it! But still, it might be better to use builtins instead of replacing characters inside of your data. Of course, if they solve your problem. But they usually do :) @Scorpionk

Comment: Yeah. You are right. Also safe and esacpejs seems easier than writing replace() function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [**safe**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) built-in template filter on your `{{jsondata}}`. 
In your situation it should look like this:

`var jsondata={{ jsondata | safe }}`